# How can I load a gif image in React Native?

Tags: android, react-native, gif

I want to load a gif image in `React Native`, but the image was not animated. I tried some solutions but it still not working. Help me.

> Note: I used React Native version 0.44 (the lastest version at the moment)

I tried add some code to `dependencies` in `android\app\build.gradle` like below:

```
compile 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-base-support:0.11.0' 
compile 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-gif:0.11.0'
```

and another on `android\app\proguard-rules.pro`

```
-keep class com.facebook.imagepipeline.animated.factory.AnimatedFactoryImpl {
  public AnimatedFactoryImpl(com.facebook.imagepipeline.bitmaps.PlatformBitmapFactory, com.facebook.imagepipeline.core.ExecutorSupplier);
}
```

But, no way can make my gif image working.
Thanks

Comment: Seem like it was working pre RN 0.43 but some people reported workarounds or upgrades here: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/13345

Comment: thanks @funkysoul, it's working now, thanks so much :)